# React TypeScript: How to clear an input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const emailInput = document.getElementById("loginEmail");
emailInput.value = ''
...
<input
  id="loginEmail"
  value={state.email}
  type="input" 
  className="input-text" 
  name="email" 
  placeholder={txt.emailAddress}
  onChange={formValue}
></input>
```

The error I'm getting on line 2 in the example above is `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the `value` for `input` element. To clear the value just reset the `state` variable.

```
this.setState({ email: "" });
```

Here is the small code for you

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputVal: "Clue Mediator"
    };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.clearInput = this.clearInput.bind(this);
  }

  clearInput() {
    this.setState({ inputVal: "" });
  }

  // handle input change event
  onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter your value here..."
          value={this.state.inputVal}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
        <input type="button" value="clear" onClick={this.clearInput} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the working demo for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-darkness-rybj2

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: the value is whatever the user types, so how do i assign it?

Comment: If you are work with `reactjs` then create `state` variable and assign in `value`. Check my updated answer for it.

Comment: Here is the working demo for you https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-darkness-rybj2. I have updated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should control the value of input in React

```
<input
  id="loginEmail"
  value={this.state.email}  
  type="input" 
  className="input-text" 
  name="email" 
  placeholder={txt.emailAddress}
  onChange={formValue}
></input>
```

In order to clear a value:

```
this.setState({
  email: ''
});
```